# pandas dataseries - How to address difference in days

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe navTable whose index is a series of dates.

I needed to find the difference between the consecutive dates in index

```
                 Delta  
2016-08-10       0.006619  
2016-08-12       0.006595  
2016-08-14       0.006595  
2016-08-17       0.006595  
2016-08-18       0.006595
```

I want a new column `Days_Diff` which would give me difference in subsequent dates (in index). Therefore my output should look like this

```
             Delta      Delta_Days
8/10/2016   0.006619    None 
8/12/2016   0.006595    2 
8/14/2016   0.006595    2 
8/17/2016   0.006595    3 
8/18/2016   0.006595    1
```

I tried this first:

```
navTable['Index'] = navTable.index
navTable['Days_Diff'] = navTable['Index'] - navTable['Index'].shift(1)
navTable['Delta_Days'] = navTable['Days_Diff'].days
```

Outright, this was not accepted as it was complaining about "days cannot be applied on Series"

So, I tried this:

```
navTable['Index'] = navTable.index
navTable['Days_Diff'] = navTable['Index'] - navTable['Index'].shift(1)
navTable['Delta_Days'] = [ eachDayDiff.days for eachDayDiff in list(dataTable['Days_Diff']) ]
```

Understandably, it is complaining about the first element with is `Null`.

> 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'days'

Question 1) Am I handling this scenario efficiently?
Question 2) How to I address

> 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'days'

For the record, first element is of type `pandas.tslib.NaTType`
Rest are of type `pandas.tslib.Timedelta`

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you will use the `diff()` function to calculate the adjacent difference and you can convert the index to a normal series and then use the `diff()` function which gives a series of `time delta` data type:

```
df.index.to_series().diff()

# 2016-08-10      NaT
# 2016-08-12   2 days
# 2016-08-14   2 days
# 2016-08-17   3 days
# 2016-08-18   1 days
# dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

To convert the time delta data type to numeric types:

```
import numpy as np
df['Delta_Days'] = (df.index.to_series().diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(float)

df

#              Delta  Delta_Days
#2016-08-10 0.006619         NaN
#2016-08-12 0.006595         2.0
#2016-08-14 0.006595         2.0
#2016-08-17 0.006595         3.0
#2016-08-18 0.006595         1.0
```